# ref and out in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli, pass-by-reference

I know that the C++/CLI code

```
void foo(Bar^% x);
```

transforms into

```
Void foo(ref Bar x);
```

What is the C++/CLI code that becomes

```
Void foo(out Bar x);
```

?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the OutAttribute:

```
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;    
void foo([Out] Bar^% x);
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no such specific syntax in C++/CLI.  I think you can get fairly close by adding the `OutAttribute` to modify the parameter.  But I'm not sure that achieves the exact same semantics as C# `out`.

The concept of `out` is for the most part limited to C#.  The CLR really only sees `ref` parameters.  The `out` concepts is achieved via a mod opt I believe and most languages ignore it.

Comment: It is the pass-by-reference syntax with `OutAttribute` applied to the parameter as you say.  It creates the exact same metadata as with C# `out` parameters.  By "not... the exact same semantics" are you referring to the fact that in C# the parameter starts out uninitialized and must be definitely assigned before the function returns?

Answer (score 0):

"Sorry for my English" In C++ you have "pointers" for example:

```
int a = 0;
int *b = &a;  // '*' means that it's a pointer variable, '&' - give you a place in memory there has an object 'a'.
*b = 1; // '*' then if you want to get information which in this memory, you need to put the '*'.
```

Example for Functions

```
void Foo(int *pa) 
{
   (*pa)++;
}
void main()
{
   int a = 0;
   Foo(&a);
}
```

As you see it works like ref and out hotkeys in C#