# .NET interface type definition in Visual C++

Tags: c#, c++-cli, clr

I need to write an interface in Visual C++, what will be used in C# project. I need to use out parameter in C#, how will i make C++ signature?

C++ code like

```
public interface class Iface
{
public:
    System::Object^ Method([out] bool there);
};
```

and C# must be

```
public class TestObj : Library.Iface
    {
        object Library.Iface.Method(out bool there)
        {
            there = true;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How will i write my C++ interface?

Comment: I believe that C++/CLI only gives you normal and `ref` parameters (when you use the `%` managed reference sigil).

Comment: Why do you want to use an `out` why exactly is wrong with your code?  One problem I see is you declared it as an interface class something tells me that isn't correct.

Comment: Thank you. I have not many experence in C++/CLI

Comment: Some related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514237/ref-and-out-in-c-cli
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186477/in-c-cli-how-do-i-declare-and-call-a-function-with-an-out-parameter

Answer (score 3):

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
interface class Iface
{
    Object^ Method([Out] bool% there);
};
```

Comment: @Hans: Wrong.  It affects the C# compiler dataflow analysis.  Without the `[Out]`, the C# compiler will demand that the argument is definitely assigned before the call.  With the `[Out]`, the C# compiler will require the implementing method to definitely assign the parameter before returning.

Comment: Hmm, no, C# does in fact use *out* for the implementation method.  This answer is correct, +1.